# ReactNavigation: How do avoid screen re-rendering when not visible

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I notice the all the screens are being re-rendered as I navigate through the app even though they are not active(visible). The only exception are the screens in TabNavigator with LazyLoad set to true. If yes, how do I suppress the rendering i and trigger the render only when visible

Comment: I've noticed the same. Containers even are not subscribed for `state.nav` but re-renders anyway and it's strange.

Answer (score 1):

You should use shouldComponentUpdate to check data from redux to decide if you need re-rendering your component. 
It uses the same api in react. You can check here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Answer (score 0):

With React Navigation 6 (I don't know about earlier versions) you can use the `blur` event in combination with the `useFocusEffect` hook to create a custom hook:

```js
import { useFocusEffect, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export const useScreenIsActive = (dependencies = []) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
      setIsActive(false)
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation].concat(dependencies))

  useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => {
    setIsActive(true)
  }, dependencies))

  return { isActive }
}
```

You can use the `isActive` flag to `return null` after your effects and before anything else. By doing so your component keeps mounted (and waiting for becoming focused again) but saves resources by skipping rendering.

The docs also contain class-based examples: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/#when-to-use-focus-and-blur-events-instead

Answer (score 0):

To avoid re render of previous screen after navigation I used isFocused() which is a method of navigation

`if (this.props.navigation.isFocused()) { //write the code that should not re render after navigation }`

Answer (score -1):

It's not how react-navigation working. It's re-render a component if it has been garbage collected. For example if you navigate too many page and come back to first page, it will be re-rendered. But in the other situation, there wouldn't any re-render. I think you are changing props of your screens. If you couldn't find the problem provide your code here.

Comment: I am using redux, and may have not used it properly. Checking.

Comment: If your screens have a container, it's possible. They receive a props from redux store which has changed.